# Error when I import a .so file into android studio

Tags: java, android, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm trying to import the libchilkatzip.so library into my Java Android Project. I'm using Android Studio with Windows 8.1 - 64x.

In the code line `System.LoadLibrary("libchilkatzip")` I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load CkZip from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/de.xy.xyz-107.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/de.xy.xyz-107]: findLibrary returned null
```

I have imported all `.so` files under the `libs` directory: "armeabi", "armeabi-v71", "mips" and "x86". The Java files are also in my Project under com.chilkatsoft.

Comment: Where are your armeabi and armeabi-v71 directory located at? whats their path? It seems the compiler is looking for these files on C:../../../data/app and on C:../../../data/app-lib path.

Comment: The Project structure is like this: 

ProjectName\app\libs\armeabi\libchilkatzip.so and
ProjectName\app\libs\armeabi-v71\libchilkatzip.so

Answer (score 0):

You can move all of your .so files and any other files into your Own Project and put them in one folder within your project. Also if you are running the Java compiler and since this error is from java.lang class, you can add all the .so files and any other library under your Java directory/path; C:/Java/jdk1.7.0_xx/lib.